# Bootstrap 5 how to align text right in a navbar?

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I have the following navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/">Accueil</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/depreg">Visualisation région/département</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/reprad">Visualisation garages</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <span class="navbar-text">
                <i class="bi bi-info-circle" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" data-bs-html="true"
                    title="test content">
                </i>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I would like to align the span tag to the right. According to the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/#placement), the above should have aligned the span on the right, but it does not.

How can I properly align my span tag on the right of the navbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `ms-auto` class to the span to push it to the right.
So `<span class="navbar-text">` becomes `<span class="navbar-text ms-auto">`.

Comment: Writing `ms-auto` to right align text is completely unintuitive. Like other things in Bootstrap 5. It's annoying that `navbar-text` doesn't take up full width if I change it to a div (because of the parent's flex property). Would have thought by rewriting Bootstrap so many times they'd figured out to make it logical...!